# I want to append an element to xml’s lead

Tags: python, xml, xml-declaration

sport.xml is

```
<sports>
  <sport order="001">
    <name>football</name>
    <orgin>England</orgin>
  </sport>
  <sport order="002">
    <name>baseball</name>
    <orgin>America</orgin>
  </sport>
</sports>
```

I want to append an element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

to xml’s lead

As a result,I want to make a xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<sports>
  <sport order="001">
    <name>football</name>
    <orgin>England</orgin>
  </sport>
  <sport order="002">
    <name>baseball</name>
    <orgin>America</orgin>
  </sport>
</sports>
```

I wrote codes,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('c:\\pg\sport.xml') 
root = tree.getroot()
```

but I cannot do it.
How should I write codes to append the element to xml’s lead?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` is an ***XML declaration***, not an element.

Comment: @kjhughes Yes,it is so.But I want to append something else XML declaration the element to xml’s lead.

Comment: Your comment is unclear but appears to merely restate your question.  See duplicate link for how to output an XML declaration.